# Promise All & await Async function return always promise pending

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently programming object oriented. I had programmed a project as a prototype, it works wonderfully now. I would now like to chop it up one by one.

I always get Promise Pending, what am I doing wrong?

```
exports.orderArticles = async (data) => {
    let indices = [];

    await Promise.all([data]).then((results) => {
        let dataIndex = results;

        for(let results of dataIndex){
            for(let res of results){
                indices.push(res);
            }
        }
    });
    console.log(indices)
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: is `data` not an array to begin with?

Comment: `Promise.all([data])` doen't make much sense. You are wrapping `data` in an array, and then waiting for all 1 elements in that array to resolve. Mixing `await` and `.then()` is also a recipe for disaster. Where exactly do you get your pending Promise? This looks like an attempt to synchronize asynchronous code (which is not possible).

Comment: my other function also gives this an array, this data comes from the database.

```exports.subsitesIndex = async (data) => {

    console.log(data instanceof Array);

    try{
        let dataSites = [];

        for(let i = 1; i<= data.length; i++){
            dataSites[i]  = Promise.resolve(Subsites.fetchSubSites(i));
        }

    return dataSites;

    } catch (err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }
}```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this

```js
exports.orderArticles = async (data) => {
    let indices = [];

    const results = await Promise.all([data])
    for(let result of results){
            for(let res of result){
                indices.push(res);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(indices)
    return indices;
}
```

Comment: now I get an empty array